# React - Arrow functions and this and scope

Tags: reactjs, scope, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have the following code.

```
let myapp = this;
      myref.on('value', function (snapshot) {
        myapp.updateUsers();
    });
```

I am trying to get rid of the code which fixes the scope issue. Can I convert this to an ES6 arrow function?

Alternatively is there a way to access the react root app?

```
 class App extends Component {}
```

Comment: In what context your code is written? inside the `App` class?

Comment: yes it is inside the app class

Answer (score 2):

When you are inside a `class` and using an arrow function then `this` will get its reference binding to the instance via the lexical scope, instead of dynamic binding like you get with plain normal functions.
So when you want to use a method within the `class` you can reference the `class` instance with the `this` key word:

```
someFunction = () => {this.updateUsers()}
```

Simple Example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  myfunc1 = (str) => {
    console.log(str);
  }

  myFunc2 = () => {
    this.myfunc1('hi func 2')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.myFunc2}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it but the on('value') is a firebase event. So I need to write it so the function takes a parameter and an event. I tried all the versions of the syntax I could think of. Maybe just need t do it this way?

Comment: where do you run `myref.on()` perhaps show some more code so we can see a bigger picture

Comment: finally got it  myref.on('value', (snapshot) => {  I was sure tried this! Thanks.