# Differences about functions React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
addNumber= () => { this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 }) }

addNumber() { this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 }) }
```

Whats the difference between these? The second one is not working it does not increase the number in the text

Comment: This may have been asked here already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400259/react-arrow-functions-and-this-and-scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `addNumber() { this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 }) }` (second function), the function has its own context and `this` in this function is different from `this` in the first function. you can send your context to the second function and it will work correctly. for do that, you can call it like this:

```
addNumber() { this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 }) }

//call:
this.addNumber.bind(this)
```